# How to fetch public video detail using Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch Facebook public video detail like the video title and thumbnail.

Here is my code

```
<?php

session_start();
require 'Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
   'app_id' => '',
   'app_secret' => '',
   'default_graph_version' => 'v11.0',
]);

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/{video_id}',
    '{access-token}'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
echo $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

?>
```

the above code is returning this error

> Graph returned an error: (#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature.

What does it mean?

Comment: You either need a page access token, granted by a page admin that gave your app `pages_read_engagement` permission, or you need to submit your app for review to be allowed to use the feature `Page Public Content Access` if you want this for pages you do not have admin access to.

Comment: Can’t we do this without access token? Maybe regex could do the job @CBroe

Comment: Scraping is not allowed, plus Facebook changes class names etc. to make any such attempts harder.